# Match only alpha characters and whitespace

Tags: php, regex

I have this regex:

```
/[^a-z\s]/i
```

This is suppose to match any character from a-z and A-Z and any whitespace encountered. It works for characters, but not for spaces, why ?

I'm checking in php like this :

```
if (preg_match('/[^a-z\s]/i', $username)) {
    ...
}
```

I'm checking to see if the username contains any other character than letters ( a-z,A-Z ) or than space.

Comment: The `^` inverts the meaning of the pattern. "match any character which is NOT a-z or whitespace".

Comment: I know, because I give an error if the condition returns true, so if I would remove `^` I would do `if(!(preg_match('/[^a-z\s]/i', $username))){...}`. So that's the way I need it, the problem seems to be that it doesn't see spaces, even more than one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex should like this:
`/^[a-z\s]+$/i`

```
if (preg_match('/^[a-z\s]+$/i', $username)) {
    //the username is ok.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`/[^a-z\s]/i` will only match characters that **aren't** in the case-*insensitive* set a-z and space. Try removing the `^`, which negates the characters inside your brackets. The pattern to match all letters and spaces should read:

`/[a-z\s]/i`

Note that `\s` won't just match spaces. It will match **any** whitespace character (like tabs and newlines) as well.

If you want to force matches to **begin** with a letter or space, you must move the `^` outside of the brackets like so:

`/^[a-z\s]/i`

Finally, if you're trying to match strings that begin with one or more occurrences of letters and spaces you need to add the `+` modifier. Otherwise it will only match a single character:

`/^[a-z\s]+/i`

Answer (score 2):

because the ^ character is an anchor and you've placed it incorrectly...if you use ^ and $ for the start and end string markers they need to appear at the absolute beginning and end respectively.

So it sounds like you'd want:

```
^[a-zA-Z\s]$
```

or if you want to match multiples of alpha and/or spaces then:

```
^[a-zA-Z\s]*$
```

Answer (score 1):

Works for me! Perhaps you should include a fully reproducible example, but it picks up spaces for me.

You can also rewrite this regex to do the opposite, which is a bit more obvious for me personally:

```
/^[a-z\s]*$/
```